# R: rpart or random forest for datasets with multiple rows per subject

Tags: r, random-forest, rpart

I have some fundamental understanding problem with rpart or train(method="rf") in R.

My data is currently structured as follows:

Around 100 subjects, each has 2048 rows (so around 204,800 rows) with 28 columns, there is a column with the unique subject ID (2048x) and the target variable per subject I try to predict (0 or 1, 2048x).
The actual data are measurements in a ppm scale, so the first column of the actual measured data is a ppm unit and the following columns are the measurements for this specific ppm subsection, which is repeated for 2048 ppm subsections in increasing order.

How do I need to restructure the data or start rtree/train in order to let R treat each 2048 rows as one data unit?